# Elastic IP not working for Network Load Balancer

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I have created a Network Load Balancer on AWS with two public subnets. For one of the subnet, I have allocated a static elastic IP. When trying to reach the NLB using the static IP I get `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`, but it works correctly when using the DNS name of the NLB (e.g. xxx-yyy.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com).

If I run the command `host xxx-yyy.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` I get a different IP from the static one (probably the IP autoassigned by AWS on the other subnet).

Any idea why the elastic IP is not working for the NLB?

Comment: I know this works because I did it last week. Please edit your question to provide screenshots of relevant console screens, we need more information to help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to wait some time (about 1 hour in my case) before the static IP starts to work properly.